# How to insert these non-ascii characters as html content?

Tags: html, unicode

Any non-ascii representation is written as `&#xYYYY`.

As per below code,

### [image]

Editor is `Sublime Text`.

How do I represent these emoticons in html?

Comment: What is not working? Are you adding the semi-colon at the end of the escape sequence? Is there some problem with simply putting the characters directly in the HTML?

Comment: @torazaburo  Firstly, I do not know the editor through which this code screen shot is coming from? I am currently using Sublime text. How do I represent these emoticons using sublime? Using `&#xYYYY` or directly inserting emoticons?

Comment: You can either directly insert the emoticon, or you can include its hexadeimal representation, which must end with a semi-colon.

Comment:  ← copy, paste, save as UTF-8, ensure browser interprets site as UTF-8, done.

Comment: @torazaburo Using sublime text, what is the procedure to directly insert emoticon?

Answer (score 2):

I found this Sublime Text 3 Plugin to insert emojis into the editor.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emoji

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you save the file you're editing using the `UTF-8` character encoding, and make sure it is delivered with a suitable content type header, such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` you don't need to do anything at all.

Another option, as others have noted, is adding them as [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) instead. In order to do that you would need to know their character codes. How to do that differs between different environments, but there are [multiple questions on SO about that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicode+character+to+hexadecimal+code).

Here's how you could do it in Python (Python 3, you'd need to use `u""` strings in earlier versions):

```
chars = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
]

for char in chars:
    print("{}: &#{:02x};".format(char, ord(char)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent Emoticons in html as its unicode symbol formatted as `&#xAAAAA;` ([some unicode list](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode))

```
<div>&#x1F601;</div>
```

I am using sublime text as editor and when you see it on browser it should look like these:

[image]