# How embedded image works in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I was reading a blog and I came across a simple snippet that rendered image without `img` tag or CSS. I would like to know how this works.

**Snippet:**

```html
<span id="pie"></span>
```

Copy and paste it in HTML file and the image gets rendered. How does this work? and what type of image can we embed in here?

Comment: It's a Unicode emoji

Comment: This is "not really" an image, it's a character

Comment: its emoji like 

Comment: Already discussed this in my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert these non-ascii characters as html content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340857/how-to-insert-these-non-ascii-characters-as-html-content)

Comment: A bit off-topic, but there are also funny table replacements of small images like here https://pgl.yoyo.org/img2html/ but a bit hard to find ;-) But easier would be a dataURLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an image, but an emoji inserted using the decimal (dec) or hexadecimal (hex) code (just like you render spaces using `&nbsp;`). 
Check examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_smileys.asp)

Here's another example snippet

```
<span style='font-size:100px;'>&#129312;</span>
```

and it renders : 
🤠

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you can do that is because the "image" that is used is actually an emoji. Emojis are considered to be characters, like letters in the alphabet, but it has colors. That's why it can be rendered without an `<img>` tag.